# JAVA nested while loop error -should be amazingly simple

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I am working on a assignment for my beginner Java class. The program is a math quiz utilizing a nested while loop. I am having a problem with the program ending prematurely. Here is the code for the chunk that is generating the issue:

It is supposed to loop the number of times inputted as NumberOfQuestionsInteger, however it only loops once regardless of what you enter for NumberOfQuestionsInteger.

The code is a bit sloppy because I have been messing with everything trying to get it to work.

edit: updated to full code.

The Code Works When I Disable The threeTries loop.

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random; //import Random class

public class HroudaASSN2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     String NumberOfQuestions = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How Many Questions Would You Like To Answer?");
     int NumberOfQuestionsInteger = Integer.parseInt(NumberOfQuestions); //Converts string to Integer, I named it NumberOfQuestionsInteger so as to make that clear.

     int score, threeTries;
     threeTries = 3;
     score = 0;


     while (NumberOfQuestionsInteger > 0) // Allows the program to run until exited.
        {

         Random firstNum1 = new Random(); //create an object of Random class
         int firstNum = firstNum1.nextInt(100) + 1; //generate number between 1 and 100.

         Random secondNum2 = new Random(); //create an object of Random class
         int secondNum = secondNum2.nextInt(100) + 1; //generate2 number between 1 and 100.

             while(threeTries > 0){
                 String Answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Score :" + score +"\ntries remaining: " + threeTries + "\n\n\n" + firstNum + "+" + secondNum);
                 int AnswerInteger = Integer.parseInt(Answer); //Converts string to Integer.


                    if (AnswerInteger == firstNum + secondNum)
                    {
                        threeTries = 0;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Correct! \n +5 Points!");
                        score = score + 5;
                        NumberOfQuestionsInteger = NumberOfQuestionsInteger-1;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        threeTries = threeTries - 1;
                        NumberOfQuestionsInteger = NumberOfQuestionsInteger-1;
                    }
             }
        }
                    /* if (threeTries > 0);{
                         comment.equals("Please Try Again!");
                         }
                         else
                             {comment.equals("No Attempts Remaining!");
                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Wrong! \n -1 Point! \n Please Try Again!");
                             score = score--; }   */




}
        }
```

Comment: Please put the complete code, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Declaration/initial value of threeTries is not shown, that is important

Comment: You are decrementing `NumberOfQuestionsInteger` inside your inner loop. If this loop is for answers only then consider moving `NumberOfQuestionsInteger = NumberOfQuestionsInteger - 1;` to outer loop.

Comment: Also you don't need to use `Type` suffixes like `..Integer` in situation where variable name is `NumberOF..` and its type is numeric. Another thing is that variables in Java should start with lower-case. For more details about code style take a look at [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: @ Pshemo I originally the decremented control loop variable outside, but i moved it inside in a desperate troubleshooting edit. As far as the proper conventions for naming variables, I am aware. I can worry about polishing the code up after I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. decrement `NumberOfQuestionsInteger` in outer loop so move

   ```
   NumberOfQuestionsInteger = NumberOfQuestionsInteger - 1;
   ```

   from your `if`s in inner loop to outer loop.
2. reset number of available tries before each inner loop so move

   ```
   threeTries = 3;
   ```

   at start of your outer loop
3. You don't need few instances of `Random` class. One is enough. Also don't initialize it in loop. Do it before loops like

   ```
   Random rand = new Random();
   while(NumberOfQuestionsInteger > 0){
       int firstNum = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
       int secondNum= rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
       //...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
threeTries = 3;
while(threeTries > 0){
   String Answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Score :" + score +"\ntries remaining: " + threeTries + "\n\n\n" + firstNum + "+" + secondNum);
                int AnswerInteger = Integer.parseInt(Answer); //Converts string to Integer.
                if (AnswerInteger == firstNum + secondNum)
                {
                    threeTries = 0;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Correct! \n +5 Points!");
                    score = score + 5;
                }

                else
                {
                    threeTries = threeTries - 1;
                }
}
NumberOfQuestionsInteger = NumberOfQuestionsInteger-1;
```